# Sign with openssl utility, verify with python script

Tags: python, openssl, cryptography, sign, verify

I would like to verify signature for file that has been signed with the command-line utility, from within the python.

My command line.

```
openssl pkeyutl -sign -in data.sha256 -inkey device.key -out data-pss.sign -pkeyopt digest:sha256 -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -pkeyopt rsa_pss_saltlen:32 -pkeyopt rsa_mgf1_md:sha256
```

My python script.

```py
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization 

# client cert -> get public key
with open('device.pem', 'rb') as fc:
    cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(fc.read(), default_backend())
    public_key = cert.public_key()

# private key
with open('device.key','rb') as fk:
    private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(fk.read(), password=None, backend=default_backend())

# data sha256 that has been signed
with open('data.sha256', 'rb') as fd:
    data_sha256 = fd.read()

# data signature done by command line
with open('data-pss.sign', 'rb') as fds:
    data_sig = fds.read()

public_key.verify(data_sig,
                  data_sha256, 
                  padding.PSS(
                    mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA256()),
                    salt_length=32
                  ),
                  hashes.SHA256())
```

I get `cryptography.exceptions.InvalidSignature`.

If i do signing via python - no problem - the verification is successeful.

```py
data_sig_py = private_key.sign(data_sha256,
                               padding.PSS(
                                 mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA256()),
                                 salt_length=32
                               ),
                               hashes.SHA256()
                              )

public_key.verify(data_sig_py,
                  data_sha256, 
                  padding.PSS(
                    mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA256()),
                    salt_length=32
                  ),
                  hashes.SHA256())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Python code, the **already hashed** data is passed in the second parameter of [`RSAPublicKey#verify()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa.RSAPublicKey.verify). In this case a `Prehashed` instance must be passed in the fourth parameter of `RSAPublicKey#verify()`, i.e. specifically `utils.Prehashed(hashes.SHA256())`, see also this [example](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#verification).

Currently a `HashAlgorithm` instance is passed as the fourth parameter, i.e. specifically `hashes.SHA256()`. This is also possible, but only if instead of the already hashed data the original data (i.e. **not hashed data**) is passed in the second parameter. `RSAPublicKey#verify()` hashes *implicitly* in this case.

I.e. in the current Python code the data is *double* hashed when verifying. In the OpenSSL statement, however, the only *single* hashed data is signed. For this reason, the verification with the Python code fails.
If the signature is created with the Python code (as in your last example), the data is also hashed *twice*, thus resulting in successful verification.

Comment: Thank you for a complete explanation.